# How Does the Smart Control Parameter #173 from Ubuntu smarctl / gnome-disks for the Samsung MZ-7TY2560 reconcile with Linux HDSentinel Rating of 52%

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, disk, error-handling, disk-management

From the Ubuntu version of HDSentinel, it reports health of 52% because of:

```
# HDSentinel 
Hard Disk Sentinel for LINUX console 0.20.10851 (c) 2023 info@hdsentinel.com
Start with -r [reportfile] to save data to report, -h for help

Examining hard disk configuration ...

HDD Device  0: /dev/sda             
HDD Model ID : SAMSUNG MZ7TY256HDHP-00000
HDD Serial No: S2YXNB0HC02388
HDD Revision : MAT0100Q
HDD Size     : 244198 MB
Interface    : S-ATA Gen3, 6 Gbps
Temperature  : 19 °C
Highest Temp.: 19 °C
Health       : 52 %
Performance  : 100 %
Power on time: 2015 days, 11 hours
Est. lifetime: 52 days
Total written: 53.88 TB
  The status of the solid state disk is PERFECT. Problematic or weak sectors were not found. 
  The health is determined by SSD specific S.M.A.R.T. attribute(s):  #173 Wear Leveling Count
    It is recommended to continuously monitor the hard disk status.
```

However, reviewing the smartctrl information in Ubuntu results in:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     SAMSUNG MZ7TY256HDHP-00000
Serial Number:    S2YXNB0HC02388
...
Firmware Version: MAT0100Q
User Capacity:    256,060,514,304 bytes [256 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
...
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
...    
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   090   090   000    Old_age   Always       -       48372
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       90
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   052   052   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       408
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       69
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
...
```

Also Ubuntu's "gnome-disks" reports as follows:

[image: Ubuntu's gnome-disks smart control output]

1. If the Ubuntu gnome-disks is reporting attribute #173 (SSD Wear Leveling Count) as N/A (Not Applicable), why is the Linux HDSentinel application report a Health-level as 52%?
2. Why is the Ubuntu gnome-disks application reporting S.M.A.R.T. attribute #173 as N/A (Not Applicable), whereas the smartctrl application reports the value as 52, "Pre-Fail".
3. Does the Unix smartctrl application value of 52 mean that the wear-level-count is that of a new disk?
4. And what does the threshold from smartctrl of 005 mean for the S.M.A.R.T #173 parameter?  Is it that when the disk reports 005, that it has failed, but otherwise healthy?

With many thanks to the Ubuntu Linux community for insight and support about these.  I would hate to not use a disk that is perfectly healthy if this heath rating of 52% based on a S.M.A.R.T Parameter #173 (SSD Wear Leveling Count) of 55 is perfectly fine, just like for a new disk.

##### Reference to the HDSentinel Website

I tried to find information about how HDSentinel is determining SSD [drive health with S.M.A.R.T. parameter at this site](https://www.hdsentinel.com/smart/index.php) and also at [this site](https://www.hdsentinel.com/smart/smartattr.php).  But I did not find the reference to Parameter #173 (SSD Wear Leveling Count) at all as it relates to the utility's determination of disk health!  This is still very puzzling to me.

##### Reference to Additional Websites

At this stage, it seems that the HDSentinel application is reporting S.M.A.R.T. #173 (value 52, **SSD wear leveling count**) as the percentage health of the Toshiba SSD.  It seems that the threshold value for this parameter is "005".

However, this parameter is listed as "Pre-fail" which at this stage I understand means that the device is observing a critical parameter, but that this critical parameter has not at all failed and that the SSD disk is very-far for being eligible for warranty replacement, as the **device itself has not failed**!

I found some additional references:

[Self-Monitoring Analysis and Reporting Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis_and_Reporting_Technology) has the SMART numbers referenced as well as critical parameters versus parameters that are not critical.

[Hard Disk Sentinel Help - S.M.A.R.T.](https://www.hdsentinel.com/help/en/12_smart.html) has HDSentinel information on how to interpret the results.  In particular, from this reference, it seems that pre-fail indicates that the parameter is critical for the device performance (and warranty return).  But on the other hand, the threshold has not been crossed and the SSD is not yet eligible for warranty replacement:

> In the Status column the current status of the attribute is displayed.
> It can be:
>
> OK: the value is same or greater than the threshold. There is no
> problem.
>
> OK (Always passing): the threshold is zero so it is not possible to
> have smaller value. Usually displayed for the attributes indicating
> only statistical information.
>
> Fail: for a critical attribute the value exceeded the threshold (value
> is smaller than threshold).
>
> Usage limit exceeded: for a non-critical attribute the value exceeded
> the threshold (value is smaller than threshold).

[Samsung SSD "Wear_Leveling_Count" meaning](https://superuser.com/questions/1037644/samsung-ssd-wear-leveling-count-meaning) seems to try to tackle the question head-on.  But the problem is still there is nothing definitive that I can find for Samsung SSD's with the #173 Parameter (SSD Wear Leveling Count).

The closest [Samsung Reference to Wear Level Count attribute #177 can be found in this link](https://image-us.samsung.com/SamsungUS/b2b/resource/2016/05/31/WHP-SSD-SSDSMARTATTRIBUTES-APR16J.pdf).  It has the following definition for this Wear Level Count attribute #177 which very likely might have a different definition than for the **#173 Parameter SSD Wear Leveling Count Attribute**:

> To [quote the screenshot of the table from this reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOpKr.png):
>
> [image: Table with a description of the Wear Leveling Count]

Also this [experimental reference "Project Kenko 01 Update – Samsung 750 EVO SSDs Wear Leveling Count Exhausted" has some insight to quote](https://www.servethehome.com/project-kenko-01-update-samsung-750-evo-ssds-wear-leveling-count-exhausted/):

> [image: Part 1 of the Experimental Graph]
> [image: Part 2 of the Experimental Graph]

##### Full smartctl output

The full smartctl output (referenced initially in just its most relevant parts) follows:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
[sudo] password for stephen: 
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.5.0-15-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     SAMSUNG MZ7TY256HDHP-00000
Serial Number:    S2YXNB0HC02388
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 d4192cbd6
Firmware Version: MAT0100Q
User Capacity:    256,060,514,304 bytes [256 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Jan 31 10:05:09 2024 IST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  85) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   090   090   000    Old_age   Always       -       48372
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       90
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   052   052   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       408
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       69
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
180 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       1856
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0032   066   045   000    Old_age   Always       -       34
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0013   049   049   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       8220835
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       55168
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       85786
249 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       104640

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
  255        0    65535  Read_scanning was never started
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: I used to *love* HDSentinel as it gave such *simple* stats.. and saved your needing to read all the figures provided by the real SMART data as `smartctl` gets from the drive... HOWEVER HDSentinel creates its simplied stats from only some values meaning its can be far less accurate.   I mostly used HDSentinel in comparisons with my prior check/scans of drive(s)  (*using same version of HDSentinel).. ie. looking for values that have changed!!; if they had markedly I;d then look at `smartctl` values which I found more accurate of the two (with HDSentinel giving that quick easy opinion).

Comment: Sometimes disks can be used again. But it is prioritized to use just those disks with "100% health" to avoid any problems of Windows installation on top of a shaky stack of unstable NTFS partitions.  When creating an NTFS partition, there are a lot of blank blocks. Blank blocks on top of bad sectors are not usually a problem, and are usually not even observed.  But then when the data (the operating system) is installed on that NTFS partition -- that is the problem. Assumably, bad sectors can pop up as errors and as bad NTFS blocks that need further processing - even stopping booting sometimes.